# WIX installer: set additional text to exit dialog using custom action

Tags: wix

I am installing ASP.NET MVC website using wix. I need to show the URL of installed site on the exit screen.

I have following properties:

```
<Property Id="WEBSITE_URL" Value="NotSet" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="NotSet" />
```

Which are populated using custom actions:

```
<CustomAction Id="GetWebsiteUrl"
              BinaryKey="CustomActions"
              DllEntry="GetWebsiteUrl"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="ignore" />

<CustomAction Id="SetExitDialogAdditionalText"
              Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" 
              Value="The API may be accessed from the following URL: [WEBSITE_URL]"/>
```

InstallUISequence is following:

```
<InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action='GetWebsiteUrl' Before='ExecuteAction'>NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
      <Custom Action="SetExitDialogAdditionalText" After="GetWebsiteUrl">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

And the result string on exit screen is:

> The API may be accessed from the following URL: **NotSet**

I've tried to execute custom actions in the InstallExecuteSequence and in the logs I can see that string looks correct:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='GetWebsiteUrl' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
      <Custom Action="SetExitDialogAdditionalText" After="GetWebsiteUrl">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The result in logs:

> PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying WEBSITE_URL property. Its current value is
>   'NotSet'. Its new value: 'http://localhost:80'.
>
> PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT property. Its
>   current value is 'NotSet'. Its new value: 'The API may be
>   accessed from the following URL: http://localhost:80'.

But in UI something is going wrong.
I feel like the problem is in the InstallUISequence, but can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please advise.

Comment: In your comment below - you mention that it works invoking from the command line. I can assure you - there is no 'functional' difference except for the addition of logging. If the addition of "logging" is "allowing" the set-property to work, I might suspect the DLL has a timing/threading issue. Why do you need a custom action to obtain the website URL? Shouldn't that be part of the install "information"?

Comment: During install user can select website in iis where he wants to install the application. The application is deployed to IIS and after this, using custom action I get bindings info from selected webiste and assemble the final url.

Comment: You should only have to collect and set the property before the InstallValidate sequence action.You shouldn't need a custom action for that. A simple dialog text with a property link should have done the trick. You still might need the custom action to gather other information based on the URL - but that would be invoked alongside the wizard workflow. Full UI right?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your WEBSITE_URL property as secure in case the value isn't being properly saved across UI and Execute sequences.

Comment: I've tried to run msi using the following command to see the logs of installation via UI:   
**msiexec /i API.Installer.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt**   
and it just worked!
After this tried to add Admin="yes" to properties, but still no success when I run msi not from console.